# Is it safe to install Android L on my Nexus 4 (January 2015)

Tags: updates, nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop, bugs

I have a Nexus 4 that was killed (battery) when Google released android 4.4. It was the bug regarding battery being drained by the WiFi.

It was such a pain to make Google sending me a refurbished one that now I don't upgrade my phone as soon as a new android release is delivered.
I want to be sure it won't destroy my phone again.
According to [this](http://www.ibtimes.com/android-l-release-delayed-due-nexus-5-battery-life-bug-google-says-update-1719714), there were bug with the Nexus 5 in the beginning of android L...

So finally my question:
Is it safe to install android L on my Nexus 4 at the moment (January 2015)?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait.

I've had positive and reliable experiences running Android 5.0.1 on Nexus 10, Nexus 7, and Nexus 5.

However, my Nexus 4 experiences reboots with Android L and a friend's Nexus 4 outright powers down regularly.

That said, a bugfix Android 5.0.2 is rolling out to Nexus devices right now.  So wait.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's a shame Google is so lazy regarding the bugs with their own phones/tablets!